# How to fix XGBoost Explainer throwing Error in buildExplainer() function?

Tags: r, xgboost

After I build xgboost model and run build explainer I get
[Error Thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8BnK.png).

My training dataframe includes the target variable column called sp500.ret.ind.lag, which is 28th column.
[tree.train.sp.fin.comp.5pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vau6l.png)

My code is as follows:

```
xgb.train.data = xgb.DMatrix(data.matrix(tree.train.sp.fin.comp.5pc[,-28]), label = tree.train.sp.fin.comp.5pc[,28])

param <- list(objective = "binary:logistic", base_score = 0.5)

xgboost.cv = xgb.cv(param=param, data = xgb.train.data, folds = cv, nrounds = 1500, early_stopping_rounds = 100, metrics='rmse')
best_iteration = xgboost.cv$best_iteration


xgb.model <- xgboost(param =param,  data = xgb.train.data, nrounds=best_iteration)

##HERE ERROR GETS THROWN
explainer = buildExplainer(xgb.model, xgb.train.data, type="binary", base_score = 0.5, trees = NULL)
```

Thanks for the help!

Ive seen [Error Issue](https://github.com/AppliedDataSciencePartners/xgboostExplainer/issues/23) raised here but cannot understand the solution.  Seems there's something wrong with the DMatrix ability to retain feature names.

Ive tried loading the DMatrix of Train data again directly in the explainer to no avail.
`explainer = buildExplainer(xgb.model,xgb.DMatrix(data.matrix(tree.train.sp.fin.comp.5pc[,-28]), label = tree.train.sp.fin.comp.5pc[,28]), type="binary", base_score = 0.5, trees = NULL)`